# Is there a way to achieve something like Object[property] where property can be a variable with any valid property supplied at runtime in C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, razor

I am trying to pass a property of an object in runtime, the property can be any of 5 values. Is there a way to do this? P.S Don't be mad if you think this is too easy, I have 0 experience with C#, but I know this is possible in JavaScript so just asking if anyone has any ideas:

Original Code

```
var eventDateValue = initValues.BusinessEventForm.Event.Schedules
    .Select(item => item.EventDate)
    .Single();

var eventDate = Utility.ToJson( eventDateValue );
```

`BusinessEventForm` here can be any of 5 valid `formType` objects and needs to be replaced with something like [formType] instead of hardcoding `BusinessEventForm`in the accessor.

What I want to achieve

```
var eventDateValue = initValues[formType].Event.Schedules
    .Select(item => item.EventDate)
    .Single();

var eventDate = Utility.ToJson( eventDateValue );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Why** are you doing this? What actual problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: _"I have 0 experience with C#, but I know this is possible in JavaScript"_ - C# and JS are very different languages that work very differently to each other (JS: `object` values are (usually) mutable hashtable-based objects using the prototype paradigm while C# uses runtime-immutable nominative type definitions - and there are plenty of things in C# that are literally impossible in JS - and vice-versa too. Just to warn you.

Comment: I edited your code to move the Linq expression outside the `ToJson` call-site for readability. The behaviour of the program code is identical to how it was before though.

Comment: @dai I have a razor partial view being used for 5 different forms, the forms can be save as draft, the client side uses javascript at the moment to render draft values into forms which is messy, I would like to supply initial values to the forms directly from the FormData, and hence need to fetch values appropriate to the forms based on formType.

Comment: _"I would like to supply initial values to the forms directly from the FormData, and hence need to fetch values appropriate to the forms based on formType"_ - you need to show us **exactly** what `formType` and `FormData` are, including all relevant parts of their definition - are they classes, enums, values, etc?

Comment: @dai formType is a property of initValues object, which is basically a huge class defining all kinds of forms. formType belongs to it's own class containing other properties  related to just that form.

Comment: Unfortunately that description you give there doesn't clarify things for me - can't you just post the code?

Comment: @Dai ```var eventDate = @Utility.ToJson(initValues.BusinessEventForm.Event.Schedules.Select(item => item.EventDate).Single());``` This works, but there are other forms as well, so I can't hard code the value BusinessEventForm there, instead I want to pass a variable that would have the correct formType at runtime.

Comment: How does the call-site (where your code is) know which member of `initValues` should be used?

Comment: @dai ```var formType = ViewData["FormType"]``` It is being set by the parent form, basically hardcoded value being sent as viewData to partial view, the form does have the same property accessor which is initialized as a form object of that type.

Comment: (Warning: Off-topic) but when I'm consulting on ASP.NET Core projects I make it a point that the `ViewData` collection should never be used for passing data around because you lose static typing information. Instead, I use some custom Roslyn-based code-gen to automatically create (very) strongly-typed methods that work as an alternative to all the un-typed parts of ASP.NET Core, such as the `ViewBag`, `ViewDataDictionary`, and `<partial name="" for="" />`. Email me if you'd be interested in my tooling for this.

Comment: What exactly is `var formType` (in your comment above)? The C# compiler can only infer a static type of `Object?` for `formType` because `ViewDataDictionary` is just `IDictionary<string,object>` - so it's basically untyped  (This is why I hate the `var` keyword in C# with a passion) - if `formType` is a `string` value then that will result in a different solution to your problem than if `formType` was an `enum` - or is of a custom object class with its own embedded logic.

Comment: @Dai thanks for all the help, I got it done by using a class to access the string property value as an object. Have posted the answer in case you wanna have a look. Not sure if it's entirely the right way of doing it but this works :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone needs to reference this in the future, finally got it done like this by creating a class to access the formType propery object and using that object in place of the initial hardcoded initValue.BusinessEvent object:

```
BusinessForm GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
    {
        foreach (var prop in propertyName.Split('.').Select(s => obj.GetType().GetProperty(s)))
            obj = prop.GetValue(obj, null);

        return obj as BusinessForm;
    }

    var formType = ViewData["FormType"];
    var initValues = ViewData["initValues"] as BusinessFormData;
    BusinessForm businessFormObject = GetPropertyValue(initValues, formType.ToString());
    var eventDate = @Utility.ToJson(businessFormObject?.Event?.Schedules.Select(item => item.EventDate).Single());
```

Comment: Your use of a `foreach` statement which iterates over reflection metadata will have poor runtime performance - you can significantly improve this by caching the result for a given `obj`'s `Type` and `propertyName` pair (e.g. in a `ConcurrentDictionary<(Type objType, String propertyName),Func<Object,BusinessForm>>`). But personally I'd just use an `enum` (with `ExhaustiveMatching` for compile-time safety).

Comment: @dai Okay, mine knowledge of C# is way to low to comprehend what you want me to do, could you help rewrite the above function in the way you describe? Why I got into this is because I am working on JS part of this app and just wanted to try out if it's possible to do in Razor.

Comment: Ignore my remarks about using `ConcurrentDictionary` as it isn't necessary - instead see my far simpler approach in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

### A simpler approach: Add an `enum`-based lookup method to `initValues`'s `class`:

- I would use an `enum` for this instead of a `String` so that we can take advantage of compile-time exhaustiveness checks with the (severely underrated) [`ExhaustiveMatching` Roslyn analyzer NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExhaustiveMatching.Analyzer).
- Advantages:

  - Very fast
  - No extra memory usage
  - Compile-time guarantees that `GetInitialData` is *correct*.
  - Using `ExhaustiveMatching` ensures that if you were to ever add a new member to `enum SpecificForm` without adding corresponding `case SpecificForm.NewMember` to every `switch()` using `default: throw ExhaustiveMatching....` you'll get a compile-time error instead of an unexpected, hard-to-predict, runtime bug.
- Disadvantages:

  - Needing to manually keep `enum SpecificForm` in-sync with the actual members of `class InitialData`.

    - But this downside is hardly any worse than having to keep-track of magic strings for `string propertyName` as you are right now.
    - And actually, you can probably knock-out a Roslyn codegen tool in an hour which would automagically re-generate `enum SpecificForm` based on the members of `class InitialData`.

```cs
public class InitalData // <-- I assume this is `initValue`'s type/class
{
    public BusinessFormData GetInitialData( SpecificForm form )
    {
        switch( form )
        {
        case SpecificForm.BusinessEventForm:
            return this.BusinessEventForm;
        case SpecificForm.KinkyEventForm:
            return this.KinkyEventForm;
        case SpecificForm.FuneralForMotherInLawEventForm:
            return this.FuneralForMotherInLawEventForm;
        case SpecificForm.FormForSubmittingNewEventFormsForm:
            return this.FormForSubmittingNewEventFormsForm;
        default:
            throw ExhaustiveMatching.ExhaustiveMatch.Failed( form );
        }
    }

    // etc
}

enum SpecificForm
{
    BusinessEventForm,
    KinkyEventForm,
    FuneralForMotherInLawEventForm,
    FormForSubmittingNewEventFormsForm
}
```

Usage:

```cs
SpecificForm   currentForm = (SpecificForm)this.ViewData["formType"];
//SpecificForm currentForm = SpecificForm.BusinessEventForm

DateOnly eventDateValue = initValues.GetInitialData( currentForm ).Event.Schedules
    .Select( item => item.EventDate )
    .Single();

String eventDateJson = Utility.ToJson( eventDateValue );
```